# I want to create a Voronoi diagram while retaining the data in the data frame

Tags: r, sf, voronoi-thiessen

We will use st_voronoi() to create a Voronoi diagram.

I have three questions.

**Point one.**

I understand that the argument to st_voronoi() should be the following data.

■SFC format (an error occurs in SF format)

■MULTIPOINT format(Not in POINT form.)
Is this understanding correct?

**Point two.**

If you run the following code, it will be converted to GEOMETRYCOLLECTION.
Is there a way to convert this to MULTIPOINT?

**Point three.**

The original "nz_height" contains the word "elevation".
However, the conversion to SFC format has erased that column.
I would like to figure out the elevation of each area of the Voronoi diagram.
What kind of processing should I do?

If there is anyone who knows about it, please tell us about it.

```
library(sf)
library(sp)
library(spData)

print(class(nz))

print(class(nz_height))
print(head(nz_height))
plot(st_geometry(nz_height))

#POINT to MULTIPOINT
nz_height_mp <- st_cast(nz_height,"MULTIPOINT")
print(head(nz_height_mp))

#sf to sfc
nz_height_mp_sfc <- st_union(nz_height_mp)
print(class(nz_height_mp_sfc))
print(head(nz_height_mp_sfc))


nz_height_v <-st_voronoi(nz_height_mp_sfc)

print(class(nz_height_v))
print(head(nz_height_v))
plot(st_geometry(nz_height_v),col=0)
```

Comment: I think everything you need is in the help for st_voronoi - combine point geometries to a *single* multipoint (not a vector of single-point MULTIPOINT geometries) with `c` (or possibly `st_combine`) and extract geometry  then `st_intersects` to match points with polygons.

Comment: Thank you for answering.
If possible, I'd like to know the sample code.

Comment: The code is in the help text, in the examples section. It shows how to merge points, do the voronoi, then match the points to the polygons.

Comment: Where can I find help texts?

Comment: `help(st_voronoi)`, or possibly via RStudio's interface if you are using that.

Comment: understood! Thank you very much!

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 8):

Here's a function that can take an `sf` data frame with `POINT` geometry in each row and produce the polygon geometry in the same order:

```
st_voronoi_point <- function(points){
    ## points must be POINT geometry
    # check for point geometry and execute if true
    if(!all(st_geometry_type(points) == "POINT")){
        stop("Input not  POINT geometries")
    }
    g = st_combine(st_geometry(points)) # make multipoint
    v = st_voronoi(g)
    v = st_collection_extract(v)
    return(v[unlist(st_intersects(points, v))])
}

p = st_as_sf(data.frame(x=runif(10),y=runif(10),A=letters[1:10]),coords=1:2)
v = st_voronoi_point(p)
```

`v` is now the polygon geometry vector that matches the order in the source. If you want you can then do:

```
pv = st_set_geometry(p, v)
```

to make a version of `p` but with the polygons as geometry.